# Prove the equivalence: $f$ is continuous on $A$ iff whenever $U$ is open in $\textbf{R}$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a relatively open subset of $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function on a subset $A$ of $\textbf{R}$. The following are equivalent:

(a) $f$ is continuous on $A$.

(b) if $U$ is an open subset of $\textbf{R}$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a relatively open subset of $A$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let us prove the implication $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ first.

Let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. We want to prove there is an relatively open subset of $A$ which contains $x$ and is contained in $f^{-1}(U)$.

Indeed, this is the case. if $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, then $f(x)\in U$.

Since $U$ is open, there is a positive real number $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. $f(x)\in N_{\varepsilon}(f(x))\subseteq U$. But $f$ is continuous. This means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ s.t. for every $y\in A$ the following implications hold:
\begin{align*}
y\in N_{\delta}(x)\cap A \Rightarrow f(y)\in N_{\varepsilon}(f(x))\subseteq U \Rightarrow y\in f^{-1}(U)
\end{align*}

Hence we conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ is relatively open because $x\in N_{\delta}(x)\cap A\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$, and we are done.

Let us now try to prove the second implication $(b)\Rightarrow(a)$.

We want to prove the following claim:

\begin{align*}
(\forall a\in A)(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists\delta > 0)(\forall x\in A)(x\in N_{\delta}(a)\Rightarrow f(x)\in N_{\varepsilon}(f(a)))
\end{align*}

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $a\in A$. Then $f^{-1}(N_{\varepsilon}(f(a))) = \mathcal{O}\cap A\supseteq N_{\delta}(a)\cap A$ for some $\delta > 0$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is open.

Hence we conclude that
\begin{align*}
x\in N_{\delta}(a)\cap A \Rightarrow x\in f^{-1}(N_{\varepsilon}(f(a))) \Rightarrow f(x) \in N_{\varepsilon}(f(a))
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Could someone please verify if the wording and reasoning of my solution are correct?

Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: The title needs to be re-worded -- doesn't form a complete statement

Comment: I've tried to reword it.